# TeeChart - Chart with non automatic bar aling/size

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, teechart

Is it possible to show a dynamic chart with fixed bar align and size?
I'd like to show my chart with vertical bars with width 5 and all them to right align.

On the follow attached example I built it using rectangles, so I just created the object in runtime and put it on the right side, I'd say my rectangle chart 'moves' from right to left.
I'd like to do something like that using TeeChart

I'm using TeeChart Pro 2020 + RadStudo 10.4.1 + FMX.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u32d2.jpg)

Comment: One way for achieving this would be to simply add enough 0 values to the beginning of your array. This way you make sure that the array size has enough elements to reach desired with of each element in your chart. Probably not the best solution bit it will get the job done.

Comment: It worked so far, thank you. https://ibb.co/x58VWKZ